# storing maps.LatLng in indexeddb

Tags: indexeddb

maybe a stupid question, but when i put a maps.LatLng object into an indexeddb objectstore and subsequently i get this object from the store the maps.
Then the LatLng object turned into an ordinary Object.

The console shows me this

lat: R (The non retreived LatLng)
$a: 52.470233
ab: 6.028643999999986
**proto**: R

value: Object (the retreived LanLng)
$a: 52.524495
ab: 6.059285999999929
id: 1
**proto**: Object

Can somebody tell me what to do or is best practice to save the latitude and longtitude and after getting the data transform it client LatLng object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB store [structured clone](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data) of your data.

I don't know your LatLng object. The way is your store only the data so that you can restore it. For example, suppose you want to store `latLng` object,

```
record = {id: latLng.id, lat: latLng.lat, lng: latLng.lng}
db.put('LatLng', record)

db.get('LatLng', id).done(function(obj) {
  var lat_from_store = new LatLng(obj.id, obj.lat, obj.lng);
});
```

Comment: I think my question was not really clear, i think i had also got to mention that i wanted to persist a google.maps.LatLng class.

Comment: Read structured clone algorithm. class methods are not persist. Also you should not need to persist class.

Comment: You can use GeoJSON to store all kind of geographic information inside IndexedDB.